# ghost-input with phone screen-locked

Tags: lock-screens

I use my phone to hear music via bluetooth while doing my running training.
I always screen-lock the phone and put it into a hip belt, where it sits tight. Obviously it gets shaken while I'm running. I don't use a phone case.

It randomly happens that the phone all of a sudden changes music, stops it or even starts something else like a youtube video. It does completely random stuff like going into flight mode or writing ghost emails. :-)

When I notice it because the music stopped/changed I get it out of the hip belt and see that the screen is activated.

How can that happen and what can I do to avoid it? 
I consider getting a case but since I wouldn't normally use one I'd prefer a simpler solution.

Thanks!

- Galaxy S7 edge, Android 7.0
- Screen unlock with either fingerprint sensor or pattern-unlock
- Teufel AIRY